# Formatting large numbers using numeral.js

Tags: format, numeral.js

In my app, I want to format various numbers using a library, and I have a couple of related questions (which I don't submit separately because I think they might represent a very common set of problems)

1. Format a number using a format string constant to achieve compressed literals such as `1.2k` or `1.23M`
2. Format a number using a format string constant to have a thousand delimiter applied, ragardless of client's locale settings.

I tried to achieve a formatting result, where the language thousand delimiter is actually taken into consideration

http://jsfiddle.net/erbronni/19mLmekt/

```
// load a language
numeral.language('fr', {
    delimiters: {
        thousands: ' ',
        decimal: ','
    },
    abbreviations: {
        thousand: 'k',
        million: 'M',
        billion: '',
        trillion: 't'
    },
    ordinal : function (number) {
        return number === 1 ? 'er' : 'ème';
    },
    currency: {
        symbol: '€'
    }
});
numeral.language('fr');
document.getElementById('f1').innerHTML = numeral(12345678).format('0 000') // intended output: '12 345 678' -- does not seem to work
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one one? I am trying to achieve the same thing

Answer (score 6):

Numeral.js has this built in. It can be easily achieved using `a` such as `.format('0.00a')`.

Some full examples:

`numeral(1000000).format('0a')` will return `1m`

`numeral(250500).format('0.0a')` will return `250.5k`

`numeral(10500).format('0.00a')` will return `10.50k`

Comment: can you help me with numeral(719520111111111).format('0.00a');
it says Undefined

Comment: Are you sure you have numeral installed? Does it work for other numbers?

Comment: Yes it is working perfectly for other stuff. For reference, have just edited the above mentioned fiddle , and have added the code in the last two lines. 
http://jsfiddle.net/nakulkudra/ueytroL7/

Comment: @N.K as I can see numeral can't handle too much large numbers. Even if is defined, with trillions there are some problems too